# How I can remove an object from firebase storage with java admin sdk

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I have the storage location ( Like gs://xxxxxx.appspot.com/43B92kgk7nRtN9uaIGpCAMFF3mr1/2020-12-24 13:18:59.670092.jpg ) and want to delete the object via admin SDK from my spring boot application.

In all documents they talk about blob Id , bucket name and ... ( I don't have those information), tried to find those information via storage location uri but didn't succeed.

I wonder what would be the easiest solution to remove from storage with storage location uri

Comment: As I mentioned in the question , I am using Java API not Node.js .    Your answer may help people who are using node.js and I appreciate it , but definitely not the answer that I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution that I find by trial and error, by testing different bucket names , bolb names and blob ids. (bucket name , blob name or blob Id is not obvious in most of the documentations )

I have used "xxxxxx.appspot.com" as bucket name , and "43B92kgk7nRtN9uaIGpCAMFF3mr1/2020-12-24 13:18:59.670092.jpg" as blob name with the follwing code to delete it from the storage

```
 Bucket bucket = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket("timeline-10.appspot.com");
 boolean result =  bucket.get("43B92kgk7nRtN9uaIGpCAMFF3mr1/2020-12-24 13:18:59.670092.jpg").delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node.js, the storage module in the Firebase Admin SDK just auto-initializes the regular [Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) for you. So you can use the approach shown in their [example of deleting a file](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/deleteFile.js):

```
// Deletes the file from the bucket
await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).delete();

console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
```

You may need to strip the `gs://xxxxxx.appspot.com/` from the location you have, as the bucket name has already been set for your by the Admin SDK.